# No internet access but Pip wants to look for newer version

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip

I'm trying to install matplotlib a server that is sequestered and has no internet connection. When I run pip with this command:

pip.exe install matplotlib-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl --no-index

I get this message:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyparsing!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 (from matplotlib==1.5.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyparsing!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 (from matplotlib==1.5.1)

I'm relatively new with this and have only used Pip once or twice before but always with an internet connection. This computer is sequestered on a DoD compound and is for sandbox development only. I have to go through three layers of RDP in order to get to it. I've tried everything I can think of or find but no luck.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you have to install pyparsing manually before matplotlib if you don’t have internet connection, because pip trying to install all the dependencies from internet

Answer (score 1):

On the computer with the internet, use `pip wheel matplotlib` to download all the wheel files needed for the installation (including dependencies).
Then, on the computer without the internet, use `pip install matplotlib --find-links="<directory of the wheel files>"`. This will install `matplotlib` from the local files.

Comment: Thanks! My work week is ending, so I'll try it first thing Monday morning.

Comment: I got pulled to other things so only got to this this morning. Unfortunately, now I get this message:

"Collecting matplotlib
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError <pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003427630>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/"

So it looks like it is still trying to get to the Internet. I'm stumped.